# Python, create database

Tags: python, sql, database

In the following script

```
from <app> import db

content = db.Column(db.String(4096))
class Player(db.Model):
     __tablename__ = "players"
     id = db.Colomn(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

<app> in Player()
     23 class Player(db.Model):
     24     __tablename__ = "players"
---> 25     id = db.Colomn(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
     26     name = db.Column(db.String(4096))
     27     score = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

I got the following error:

> AttributeError: 'SQLAlchemy' object has no attribute 'Colomn'

Please help, don't know what it means.

Comment: Column, not Colomn.

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel said, the problem is how you have wrote `Column` in the following line:

```
id = db.Colomn(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Change db.Colomn to db.Column as follow:

```
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Comment: Sometimes I hate myself.. thnx

Answer (score 0):

Its typo mistake/error at :

```
id = db.Colomn(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

change it to:

```
content = db.Column(db.String(4096))
class Player(db.Model):
     __tablename__ = "players"
     id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Comment: Sometimes I hate myself.. thnx

Comment: @ChrisvandenBerg Hey we do mistakes and we learn from it,so Its fine. Keep Coding!